# How to get an Item's index in QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, indexing, qtreewidget

I have a `QTreeWidget` in my project for which I want to get the index of its items.

My `QTreeWidget` is a list of tests that I want to perform. For example, ***Test 1***, ***Test 2***, ***Test 3***, ***Test 4*** etc.

***Test 2*** and ***Test 4*** have children ***Test a***, ***Test b***, ***Test c*** etc. Once ***Test 1*** is finished. I want the ***Test a*** of ***Test 2*** to be highlighted in the tree.

I need to work with indexes of the items in my tree. I have tried the following to get index of the tree widget:

```
QModelIndex currentTestStep = ui->treeWidget->currentIndex();
```

Or:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget->currentItem()); 
int y = item->indexOfChild(ui->treeWidget->currentItem());
```

The `QModelIndex` and `y` were empty in debug window. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method you used gets you the current's item ***modelIndex***, and it seems that what you need is the item's [row()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex.html#row) so you can work with it.

To do that you need to do the following:

```
 QModelIndex currentTestStep = ui->treeWidget->currentIndex();
 int y = currentTestStep.row();
```

And to get the ***modelIndex*** of the next item, you can use [siblingAtRow(int row)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex.html#siblingAtRow) as follows:

```
currentTestStep = currentTestStep.siblingAtRow(++y);
```

If you just need its row, then all you have to do is increment `y`.

Be careful of incrementing `y` past the number of children that your [topLevelItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html#topLevelItem) has, for example ***Test2*** has only `3` children.

### Another solution

You can use [itemBelow()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html#itemBelow) after getting your ***currentItem*** :

```
QTreeWidget item = ui->treeWidget->itemBelow(ui->treeWidget->itemAt(currentTestStep->column(),currentTestStep->row()));
```

### Another solution

You can use just [itemAt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html#itemAt-1):

```
QTreeWidget item = ui->treeWidget->itemAt(currentTestStep->column(),++y));
```

There are multiple ways to do this, check out [QTreeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html) documentation, and see if you can come up with another way to do what you need.

Here's an explanation of ***QTreeWidget***'s indexing that I found [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/66762-How-to-get-index-number-for-selected-item-in-QtreeWidget), read it so that you don't run into problems while iterating through your ***treeWidget***, or know what the problem is if you your program crashes:

> First, the QTreeWidget is a tree, not a list. Imagine the structure of
> a real tree. Starting at the root and trunk of the, it branches into a
> set of big limbs. Each of these big limbs splits into smaller limbs,
> and the limbs into branches, and so on, until you finally arrive at
> the leaves at the ends of the smallest branches.
>
> If you consider any leaf in the tree, what "row" is it in? You can't
> say, because the tree is hierarchical.
>
> However, you could say, "It is the fifth leaf on the second branch of
> the fourth limb off of the main trunk". This makes sense - if you
> assume there is some built-in order of branches. You start at the
> trunk, find the fourth limb (say moving clockwise from North). Once
> you find that, go to its second branch. The leaf you want is the fifth
> one.
>
> If you translate this into programming terms, there is an ownership or
> parent/child relationship between all of the branches and leaves of
> the tree. The fifth leaf has a "parent", th second branch. The second
> branch has a "parent" in the fourth limb. The fourth limb's parent is
> the trunk (or root).
>
> This is the structure used to represent a Qt tree in QTreeWidget or
> QTreeView. The QModelIndex is Qt's way of telling you exactly where
> you are in the tree. It works together with the QAbstractItemModel
> (which holds the information displayed in the tree) to help you
> navigate around the tree.
>
> So, I think your second problem of understanding is that the "row" in
> QModelIndex is not the count of items displayed in the tree view
> counting from the top of the display. It refers to the "nth" child of
> whatever the QModelIndex's parent is. It is not an absolute position
> in the tree, it is relative to its parent.
>
> In addition to each node in a Qt tree having one or more rows, each of
> these rows can have one or more columns in it (think of the tree in a
> file browser - for each file or directory, there is a list of
> attributes - name, date modified, size, permissions, etc.). These are
> the columns of the given row.
>
> A QModelIndex therefore tells you what row you are in the tree with
> respect to the item's parent and what column you are in the row
> counting from the left. If you want to find your absolute position in
> the tree, you have to go up the tree by asking for the parent of your
> item until you finally reach the top (root) of the tree, which is an
> "invalid" QModelIndex (QModelIndex::isValid() returns false).